# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle and while trying to install Gradle in my PC with Windows OS, I got the below mentioned error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
```

Only thing I did is that I followed the gradle installation steps given in gradle site [Gradle installation](https://gradle.org/install) and typed

```
gradle -v
```

in command prompt and I got the above mentioned exception. Any clue as to what had happened and how to resolve it.

This is what I have done :

> 1. Downloaded the zip file
> 2. Copied 'gradle-3.5' from the zip file to a folder I created in C drive (C:\Gradle)
> 3. Set GRADLE_HOME to 'C:\Gradle\gradle-3.5'
> 4. Set Path to '%GRADLE_HOME%\bin'
> 5. Opened cmd and typed gradle -v and got this error

Comment: I had to switch from 4.5 to 4.4.1 since apparently Spring 1.0 doesn't work with 4.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically this means that Gradle can't find your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`.

You have to follow **Step 3** and setup environment variables:

> **Microsoft Windows users**
>
> In File Explorer right-click on the This PC (or Computer) icon, then
>   click Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental
>   Variables.
>
> Under System Variables select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for
>   C:\Gradle\gradle-3.5\bin. Click OK to save.

Source: https://gradle.org/install#configure

The easiest way, is to simply use `gradlew.bat` in your project and it will auto download `Gradle` for you!

Comment: Yes. Most cases encounter this error are just missed `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` file.

Comment: @Max Peng : when getting the same error while using gradlew, yes.

Comment: This happened when I removed the gradle caches (.../.gradle/caches/) in order to upgrade some packages (jar files). Apparently had gradle workers still running, and removing the caches cut off their access to the gradle jar(s). Using --stop did the trick.

Comment: Same here. Got the message when I removed gradle caches (.../.gradle/caches/).
./gradlew --stop worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 105):

I stopped all gradle daemons by running `./gradlew --stop` and the error was resolved for me.

Comment: `gradle --stop` also could be useful

Comment: All though 5+ years ago, Worked perfect for me with Gradle 7.6. Deleted '.m2' first then: ./gradlew --stop. Then re-run the Gradle.

Comment: This was the fix for me when I deleted the Gradle cache without stopping the daemon. The existing daemon was borked as a result and needed to be stopped first.

Comment: `gradle --stop` worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after I removed the cache, the Gradle worker was running and I was getting this error

Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain

Steps I performed to resolve the error

1. Use gradle --stop or ./gradlew --stop
2. Delete the workerMain.lock file under $USER/.gradle/caches/version/workerMain
3. re-run the Gradle command