# Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain

Tags: gradle

I am trying to build build.xml file to to build Elasticsearchproject. Simply the build file is called the gradle build and then run the tests. However I am getting error regarding gradle. This is the first time for me using gradle. The error is

```
    Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
```

I already set the PATH and GRADLE_HOME in variable environment . I am using version 3.3. 
This this part of the code of build.xml where I am calling the gradle

```
  <target name="compile" description="Compile the  source code.">
    <exec executable="/bin/bash">
        <arg value="gradle"/>
        <arg value="build"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
```

Am I missing something?

Any suggestion that could solve this problem.
This question had asked before but there is only one answer and it did not solve the problem.

[Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426393/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-launcher-gradlemain)

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the dependencies in classpath?

Comment: All the dependencies should be included the gradle file. So I just need to call the gradle. So I have no dependencies to include. I just include the source and test files. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, so I checked the zip file that I had downloaded with unzip -t gradle.zip and it got me some errors. So I downloaded it again and unzip again. Check if the unzip folder has all the *.jar files at the lib folder.
After that add the path of the gradle bin folder to your PATH variable. I did not included any other dependencies or any other variable to the path.

The problem is that gradle cannot find the gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the result using an version of unzip that didn't extract all of the files and directories as they should ... or a corrupt download, as mentioned in another answer.

I just ran into this issue, as the `unzip` in my system path was taken over by the default one provided in TCC and it didn't unzip the files correctly.

`[C:\] which unzip
unzip is an internal command`

I deleted the old extracted files, and forced the usage of my familiar Info-Zip and it created the correct structure and gradle now runs.