# Gradle launcher not found when starting Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, installation

I am trying to download Gradle onto a Windows computer using the official [installation instructions](https://gradle.org/install/). I am stuck on step 4 of the manual installation process.

> Open a console (or a Windows command prompt) and run gradle -v to run gradle and display the version

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
```

I have read [Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426393/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-launcher-gradlemain), however it does not answer my question. I have correctly setup my environment variables per the instructions on the installation page.

Comment: Sounds like the unzip part didn't go well or the zip is corrupted. You didn't see any errors while downloading or unzipping? Try wiping everything and do it again. If you chose the full distribution, it will be about 140MB zipped and 250MB unzipped. The binary-only distribution is about 100MB zipped and 110MB unzipped on my machine.

Comment: @BjørnVester If I delete the files and start over, will I need to first remove that path from the environment variables, or can I just leave it as is for the next download? I'm worried it will cause some error on my computer is I keep the path there once I delete it and the path no longer exists.

Comment: You can have entries in the PATH variable that doesn't exist - they will just be ignored, so that shouldn't be a problem.