# gradlew genSource command in terminal is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, gradlew, minecraft-fabric

I am trying to make a Minecraft mod but when I need to do
`.\gradlew genSource` it keeps showing this error:

```
Fabric Loom: 0.10.66
Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Could not write standard input to Gradle Worker Daemon 3.                                              
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed                                                          
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)                                
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

> Task :genSourcesWithCfr FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':genSourcesWithCfr'.
> Failed to stop decompile worker JVM

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

and I have no idea how to fix it :(. I've tried other methods but still it does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426393/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-launcher-gradlemain, follow the accepeted answer? seems like a similar issue