# "Error: Could not find or load main class and Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:" when checking gradle -version on my command promot

Tags: gradle

Hi I have installed Gradle (tried 7.1.1 and 8.5) on Windows 10 machine.

1. User variable and System Variable "GRADLE_HOME"  is set to C:\Gradle\gradle-8.5.
2. User variable and System Variable "Path" is having  C:\Gradle\gradle-8.5\bin.
3. User variable and System Variable "JAVA_HOME"  is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19.0.1
4. User variable and System Variable "Path" is having  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19.0.1\bin.

Now When I open Command prompt as Admin and type: Java -version I get
openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)

But when I type:  gradle -version  I get

Error: Could not find or load main class and
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and

Please help to fix this issue

I tried [Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426393/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-launcher-gradlemain) but issue is not fixed